# Remote Automated Build System

Tags: c++, build-automation

I am an Electrical Engineer about to start grad school for Com Sci. Currently I work in the defense industry and as a result most services and websites are blocked here.  I'm trying to come up with a solution that will allow me to do my homework/projects while at work since they give us 2 hours a day on the clock to do school work if attending grad school. I don't have the necessary software tools on my work computer nor will I be able to get it.  I would like to setup my build system on a ubuntu box and the best solution I could think of would be to use email and possibly FTPmail to automate the build process and email me back any errors that the compiler may return.

Has anyone ever done this before or does someone know of a software package that already implements this solution.

Comment: It might help if you could describe more precisely what you might need (e.g., C compiler? Java?) and the restrictions you have to work within (white-listed set of websites? nothing on port 80?  How about https websites?).

Comment: Also, what sort of communication do you have with your home box?

Comment: There is no documentation on the restriction that I have basically its been trial and error I have found the only restriction that I know of is that we can't install outside software on our comps.  Haven't found any https sites that are blocked here so that might be an option.  But i want to use g++ compiler and would use textpad at work to code in and then email my server a package of files with a makefile in it.

Comment: Can't you just spend this time reading?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look on some web-based virtual machine/desktop tools.  Some I've seen in the wild are [icloud](http://www.icloud.com/) and [eyeOS](http://www.eyeos.org/).

Also, since installing any software is basically a no-no, you might want to check for Linux live-CDs.  You can just pre-configure the disc with the necessary tools (SCM, IDE, etc.) and boot the computer from the Live disk during your 2 hours.  Of course, that won't give you a hard drive to save your stuff, but you can just commit whatever you have before that 2 hours expires.

**Edit**: whatever you do, get this solution *approved* by your superior(s) before you attempt it.

Comment: that won't work either since we can only run approved and trusted signed software.  I ended up creating my own system with a little python scripting and email templates

Comment: @Talguy: that's a bummer.  Out of curiosity, are there any other employees (doubling as students) in computer science programs?  If so, what have they done?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will be able to access stuff outside of your network, even if you cannot install any software on your work system. One thing you can do:

Install a version control system (CVS, SVN, etc) on your Ubuntu box. You can store your projects/homework there.

Use Hudson (http://hudson-ci.org/) on your Ubunto box as your build system. You can create a job for it to checkout from your version control system and build. Anytime you want to build a project (lets say you made a change to some class), all you have to do is press the "build-now" button.

Hudson itself is almost entirely web-gui so it is easy to configure, and if you open up a port for Hudson, you should be able to access it directly from work (unless they block external websites).

Comment: Can I use FTPmail to check files out of SVN

Comment: I doubt it, but Hudson creates a workspace with all your project files when it builds it. So you could use ftpmail to access your hudson workspace on the ubuntu machine directly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a virtual machine at work?  Even if you don't have administrator access to your work machine, you may be able to use Qemu and something like Puppy Linux.   See, for example, http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/qemupuppy/

Along the lines of your original question, if you can host a machine that receives e-mail at home, you could certainly configure `procmail` (e.g., see http://www.perlcode.org/tutorials/procmail/proctut/) to match for e-mails from you with a certain subject and run a command (say, `make`).  But you'd also need to set up an filters to fetch and submit files, etc.

Comment: no VM software on my comp but procmail sounds about the right way to go.

Comment: If you use Qemu Puppy, all you need is the ability to run a new executable (Qemu, which is a machine emulator) to run the VM.  And it can all be stored on a USB key.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like VNC to remotely control your desktop or do you have restrictions for this kind of Sw too?

http://www.realvnc.com/

If I recall correctly, the client does not need to be installed, it could run from a pendrive...

http://www.pendriveapps.com/portable-vnc-viewer-realvnc/

Comment: No Thumb dirves allowed in the complex

Comment: You can create a Dropbox account and set it up to access it through Web. Put there the VNC client. Then dload the client to your computer and run it from there. Would that be allowed?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/ would allow you to access via web anything you store in your computer (up to 2GB for free).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a remote system, but it might work if you can select a boot medium on the computers you work on. Your employer might not like this.

It is possible to install a linux box on a usb hard disk and then boot from that. In this you can install all sorts of development tools and projects. You would just borrow their hardware a bit...

I wouldn't advise this if you have not worked on linux before though. Linux can be a royal pain in the ass and you might not get your development environment up and running in a year if you only have 2 hours per day to spend...

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Set your project up on [github](http://github.com). You can do editing directly there through a web browser.

Then setup continual integration on [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) on your home system, or use [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org), and/or [Appveyor](http://www.appveyor.com) to monitor your github repo and build your project when there are changes. If there are errors, you can set them up to send notifications.

The advantage of Travis or Appveyor is they are web based so you'd be able to look at the console output of broken builds where jenkins running at home probably wouldn't (I don't recall if you can get the whole output by email or not).

Comment: If you have git, you can check files out through HTTPS... edit locally then push them back up to github.